# how to disable javascript merging programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Today, i merged js from magento admin panel. After merging, my store is not working properly. I now want to disable js merging but i am unable to do this form my admin panel because now save button is also not working.
How can i disable js merging programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

1. With Magento code, in an install script:

   ```
   $installer->setConfigData('dev/js/merge_files', '0');
   ```
2. Using SQL, in the database:

   ```
   DELETE FROM core_config_data where path='dev/js/merge_files';
   ```
3. Using [n98-magerun](http://magerun.net/), on the command line:

   ```
   n98-magerun config:set dev/js/merge_files 0
   ```
4. And per request: standalone PHP script:

   ```
   <?php
   require 'app/Mage.php';
   Mage::app();
   $installer = new Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup('core_setup');
   $installer->setConfigData('dev/js/merge_files', '0');
   Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType('config');
   ```

Comment: Thanks fschmengler, i am more interested in first point but can i do something without install script?

Comment: I added a 4th option. Copy this into a PHP file in your Magento root directory, execute, then delete it